# Allow that the current_user see just user created for him

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How I permit that the current_user see just user created for him?
When I create a user I add a father_id in new user, and I need show in just users created in index.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-striped custab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>User Father</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% if current_user.father_id.present? %> // WRONG LOGIG!
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= user.father_id %></td>
         </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <p>No one user created</p>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For now, I can see all, but I need just show the created for current_user. How I can do it?

Comment: How fall in ELSE? What is the codincional when User not have created other user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
    @users = User.where(father_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

Sorry, the answer was on user_controller!

Comment: You should accept your answer as the right one. :-)